# Is there a way to remove the separator line from a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm looking for a way to completely remove the separator line in a UITableView when in the plain mode. This is done automatically in grouped, but this also changes the dimensions of the table in a way that is hard to measure. I have set the seperator line color to colorClear. But this does not completely solve the problem.

As I am trying to draw a custom background view in the cells, and I want the cells to be seamless, the one pixel line that remains in-between is causing me problems. Is there a more elegant workaround then using a grouped view and then stretching it?

Comment: Change `separatorInset` as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8561820/1418457

Answer (score 455, accepted):

You can do this with the `UITableView` property `separatorStyle`. Make sure the property is set to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and you're set.

Objective-C

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

In Swift (prior to 3)

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .None
```

In Swift 3/4/5

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: You can also do this in IB, by the way (separator => none).

Comment: This only seems to remove the separator lines within a table section. Is there a way to remove the separator lines *between* sections?

Comment: The line between sections is not really a line, but the view of the section. You can change the view by implementing `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` from the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 64):

You can do this in the storyboard / xib editor as well.  Just set Seperator to none.

[image]

Answer (score 62):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I still had a dark grey line after attempting the other answers.  I had to add the following two lines to make everything "invisible" in terms of row lines between cells.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, the separator line was not actually appearing between cells, but actually somewhere in the middle of them.

Answer (score 10):

In interface Builder set table view separator "None"

[image] 
and those separator lines which are shown after the last cell can be remove by following approach.
Best approach is to assign Empty View to tableView FooterView in viewDidLoad

self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

Answer (score 9):

In Swift:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .None
```

Answer (score 5):

There is bug a iOS 9 beta 4: the separator line appears between `UITableViewCell`s even if you set `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` from the storyboard. To get around this, you have to set it from code, because as of now there is a bug from storyboard. Hope they will fix it in future beta.

Here's the code to set it:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 2):

In the ViewDidLoad Method, you have to write this line.

```
tableViews.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

This is working Code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
{
    [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```