# iOS , how can I set the separator line style is none for only one cell ,for others the separator is default?

Tags: ios

iOS , how can I set the separator line style is none for only one cell ,for others the separator is default?

I just want to remove the separator line for the section 2,row 3 cell. And for all others ,there still exist separator line.

I know a way is to set self.tableview.separator=NONE, and for the cells who want separator just add subview. But I do not think it is a optimal way.

After use

```html
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, self.view.frame.size.width);
```

Still remain…
[image]

there is about 15px width I suppose..

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide separator line on one UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `separatorInset`:

```
if (indexPath.row == {your row number}) {
    // hide the line
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, cell.bounds.size.width);
} else {
    // show the line
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 15.f, 0.f, 0.f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply check `indexPath` in `cellForRow` method, if it's `indexPath.section == 1` then set `separator.hidden = NO`

Comment: how to set separator.hidden for cell?