# How to hide UITableView empty rows,swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I hide row lines of UITableView from those rows, what are not used. For example, look at screenshot:

[image]

Can I show just 4 lines and hide other lines what are not used? So, I show just 4 lines and further comes white screen, not lines as now

Comment: try refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like set your `tableFooterView` frame as `CGRectZero` on `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()

// set as your tableFooterView frame as CGRectZero it hides the empty rows
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Obj-c code    
    TableName.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
//Swift code
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Use this code to hide the extra row lines.

Put this code in **ViewDidLoad** or in **ViewWillApper**

Answer (score 0):

- Gave snippets in Objective-C should be same in Swift as well

In your viewDidLoad Method include

```
self.localTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

In viewDidLayoutSubViews include

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self.localTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [self.localTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([self.localTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [self.localTableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

In tableView willDisplyCell delegate method include

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

here localTableView is the outlet taken from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

// Swift 3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero) }
```