# How to remove cell seperator line for a single cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

As in the screen Shot the Cell with "log Out" text is a custom cell for this cell I want to show the separator lines, but for the UItableViewcell below it with text "logged in as user" I don't want to show any separator lines.

[image: Need to remove this separator line]

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to remove all separator lines and draw the desired separators yourself as part of the cell background.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle

Comment: @matt yeah thats the way which can be done, but i want to know if there is any way to do only for one row.

Comment: @uzairdhada i have edited my answer please check it once.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell