# How can a cell's UIImage cover the UITableView separator?

Tags: ios, swift

I subclassed UITableViewCell.  Then, in my storyboard, I added an image to the superview.  The image has constraints of:

```
left: 0
bottom: -5
width: 10
height: 10
```

The reason I put -5 as the bottom constraint is because I want it to cover the separator line.

However, in this solution, the image goes underneath the line instead of over it.

Comment: Maybe you just need to hide the separators?  Than you find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell

Comment: Just set seperator to `none` from `attribute inspector`

Comment: No, because I want a separator......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the separator view and cell's content view are at the same level in the view hierarchy you could use `bringSubviewToFront` to display the content view over the separator, however this might cover it if you use a background color for the `contentView`. All you have to do is set

```
cell.bringSubviewToFront(cell.contentView)
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If this does not suit your needs you can always implement your own custom cell with a custom separator.