# How to remove separate line from tableview row cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

All

How to remove separate line from UITableView Cell Row.
I try it but still a separate line is drawn in UITableViewCell Row.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:217.0/255.0 green:235.0/255.0 blue:244.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.text = LOREM;
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:12.0]];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    return cell;
}
```

Error Image:-
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell

Comment: Why are you setting TableView property in each cell creation ?

Answer (score 1):

try and put `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;` into your `viewDidLoad...` instead of `cellForRow...`...

Comment: Slotta I try it but still its not working .  I used UITableViewController for the class. and set non in my XIB but still its drawing seperator line in each cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from `Nib` file. Select your `tableview` and make `Separator` `None`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```