# What is this little white sliver inbetween each of my table cells called in xcode and what can I do to get rid of it?

Tags: xcode

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJv6D.jpg)

Thank you! I've already made the photos fill up the entire cell through constraints and this is the code I used to get rid of the seperator and spacing which worked well but theres still that little sliver.

```
cell.separatorInset=UIEdgeInsets.zero
cell.layoutMargins=UIEdgeInsets.zero
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0):

It is a separator, and you can make it invisible:

Objective-C

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Swift

```
tableView.separatorColor = .clear
```