# remove seperator line of table view cell in xib

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell class with a xib file.

In the cell xib,  I have set the table view cell's separator to be "Custom Insets" with left=0, right=0:
[image]

But when I run my app, it still shows bottom line as below:
[image]

How to remove the separator line in interface builder of xib file? If it is not possible, what would be the progrmattical way? (do it in interface builder is my preference by the way)

Comment: Have you removed the separator line in the tableview?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26627109/6788419

Comment: @Kerberos, could you please make an answer, your question points me to the right direction. I just forget to set "None" as separator for tableview

Comment: Custom Insets  are available for the adjustment of separator start and end space not for hide.

Comment: see this https://useyourloaf.com/blog/hiding-empty-table-view-rows/

Comment: custom offset are spacing to margin setting them 0 will not remove your sperator line, it will result in full line sperator instead of spacing 15 from leading marging

Comment: you can set sperator to none in storyboard itself

Comment: @Leem.fin Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove the separator line in the Attributes inspector of the tableview like in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set `Separator Style` of your `UITableView` to `none`

Or, programmatically

**Swift 3+**

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

**Objective-C**

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, I prefer do it in storyboard. I know your answer works. But @Kerberos' points me to the direction I prefer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To remove extra saparator line from your `UITableView` you need to set `tableFooterView` of `UITableView`

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using an old version of Xcode.If you want to remove separator line, you have to select `default` option form `separator inset` and select `none` from the `separator`.

[Follow this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrHtR.png)

Or else, you can also set by programmatically

**Swift 3+**

```
yourTableView.separatorStyle = .none
```