# Why isn't UITableViewCell's Separator View listed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, separator, subviews

I want to remove *certain* `UITableViewCell separators` (not all of them).

I see them in the UI, but don't understand why they don't get listed when I print out the subview hierarchy?

```
for view in cell.subviews {
    DDLogDebug(String(describing: type(of: view)))
}
```

[image]

This seems to happen upon initial view.  If I scroll the UITableView cells far out of view and then back again, the UITableViewCell's separator magically appears in the subview log printout.  What's going on here?

*note:*  I've only tested on the simulator as I don't own an iPhone X currently.

Comment: I *love* downvotes without an explanation.  

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with UITableViewCell's *outside of the cell* doesn't seem as reliable as simply *subclassing the cell* and taking control from within it.

Hence my solution below:

```
class myCell: UITableViewCell {

    var withSeparator: Bool = true

    func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if !withSeparator {
            self.removeBottomSeparator()
        }

    }
...



extension UITableViewCell {
    func removeBottomSeparator() {
        // Remove it if it's found.
        for view in self.subviews where String(describing: type(of: view)).hasSuffix("SeparatorView") {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
}
```

Using this method allows me to find the `SeparatorView` every time and be able to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the UITableView separators on iPhone X. I was able to solve it changing the cell background:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell: UITableViewCell = ...
   ...

   **cell.backgroundColor = .clear** // <= MAGIC LINE
   return cell
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can remove separator by using storyboard and also programatically.

> Storyboard

just click on `table view` and go to `attribute inspector` from them select `separator` and change it form `default` to `none` .

[image]

> Code

use below code in `viewDidLoad`

```
customtableview.separatorStyle = .none
```

> EDITED HIDE OR REMOVE SEPARATION FROM A SINGLE CELL

Some one already ask the commented question on this community.So [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell) is the solution for handling single cell separation.

Comment: Except I want to remove *certain* UITableViewCell separators; not all of them.

Comment: @SebastianDwornik I edited my answer for removing a certain UITableViewCell separation. Hope it helps you to solve your problem. Let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: I've read that solution before, the issue is that shifting the `separatorInset` far off the screen also seems to change the margins on an iPhone X/8plus.  Making the text label far left or right justified.  :/