# How to set UITableView cell separator to 'None' when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a UITableView with customized cells from a .xib. I have added a blue border to the top and bottom of the .xib to give a customized spacing between the cells. I don't want a separator between the cells so I set the *Separator* to *None* in the storyboard. This is the look that it gives me.

[image]

This works great until I select a cell, at which point I am seeing this (notice the white separators above and below the selected cell):

[image]

I am using this code in the `cellForRowAt` function to set the color of the selected cell to white, but this also seems to force the separator to be white:

```
let selectedView = UIView()
selectedView.backgroundColor = .white
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
```

I am trying to figure out how to remove the separator lines when the cell is selected. I have tried several things on the storyboard and in code, but haven't found anything that works.For example:

- I can't use `cell.selectionStyle = .none` because I want the cell background to turn white when selected.
- This doesn't change anything when called from viewDidAppear: `tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear`
- I tried the answer here [Hide separator line on one UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell) by Avinash but it didn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this solution worked for me.

I changed my code in the `cellForRowAt` function to the clear color:

```
let selectedView = UIView()
selectedView.backgroundColor = .clear
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
```

Answer (score 0):

try change the `tableView.separatorColor = tableView.backgroundColor` 
and set you table style to **grouped**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this didn't change anything. The style is set to grouped. I have tried setting tableView.separatorColor to several different values and none of them make a difference.