# Delete Single Separator in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to delete a single separator in a tableView. I have annotated the screenshot below to show this. I am wanting to delete the first cells top separator. My top text & search bar is in the tableView's header. How would I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Hey, Can you please share your code for more help, How to create search bar and cells?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code

Original answer for this code is @[Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell)

For mode detail please check avinash answer

```
if indexPath.row == {your row number} {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
}
```

Comment: Hi! This code turns the 1st cells bottom separator off. The top is still there...

Comment: Cells only have a bottom separator as far as I'm aware, are you sure this line is not created by the searchBar?

Comment: @DavidLintin  Does the TableView header have a separator? How could I turn that off?

Answer (score 0):

Add a separator view (UIView) as part of your Custom cell. From the nib make the separator for UITableView to none.

Answer (score 0):

tblView.separatorStyle = .none