# Hiding separator for empty cells doesn't show separator at all

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In a table view I'm hiding separator for **empty cells only** by following code which does hide separator for empty cells **but it also doesn't show separator at all**. I can't figure out why, any clue?

Alternatively is there any other way to hide separator for empty cells?

There is nothing wrong with the following code, it does work as intended on other VCs but on this particular VC it doesn't work as intended. I've checked storyboard and compared working and non working VCs. Both have exactly same attributes for the tableview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8561774/14351818

Comment: I'm aware of that trick to set separator to none and then add a view inside cell to act as separator. It's overkill as the same can be achieved by above code which works for me on many VCs but on one VC it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
```

or :

```
tableView.separatorColor = .clear
```

Comment: You got it wrong. I want to hide separator for empty cells only.

Comment: You are welcome but You are got it wrong of the tableview behaviour.  If you resize your tableview height correctly , there would be no empty cells and its separator as well.

Comment: Adjusting table height hides all separators so that's not the solution.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Anyway good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```swift
tableView?.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

It will still render separator but with empty frame, so it will not be visible for empty cells only, while original style will remain for filled one's.

Comment: Unfortunately this also has same effect as the code in my question. There is nothing wrong with my code, there seems to be something else which is causing the issue as reported in the question.

Comment: @Raymond Please share ViewController with the issue, so we can solve it together 