# Remove first line separator of UItableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

How can I hide or remove the very first line separator of the tableViewCell programmatically?

I just need to remove cell 0 top line.

Something of this nature:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
   //remove top seperator
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide separator line on one UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561774/hide-separator-line-on-one-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your `cellForRowAt` delegate function you can use:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell?.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    }
```