# How do I remove black line between table view cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have no idea about showing black line while tap on header section in table view.
Kindly share some idea about to fix this issue.
[image]

Comment: Please show us at least an image of what it looks like. Its hard to help you without seeing anything.

Comment: Show your screen imges

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925115/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-separator-line-from-a-uitableview

Comment: For image : kindly tap on 'enter image description here link'

Comment: Please post a full image of the screen at least the top portion, also try creating a custom header view from XIB and loading it.

Comment: is not a separator are you added the any uicontrols in layer

Comment: Thanks to all guys. Issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: This solution not gives help .

Comment: where r u write this code.

Comment: check the space between cells.

Comment: Yes and while tap on section header and close section header then it shows the black line. First time, there is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set the following on your tableView object:

Swift:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Objective-C:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

The black line is the separator you can remove it either from the storyBoard or through code

code 
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

or from storyBoard like

[image]

Comment: its a comment not a answer, change your answer to comment

Comment: This solution not gives help . Kindly see screen shot.

Comment: Are you adding section header view ?

Comment: Yes and while tap on section header and close section header then it shows the black line.
First time, there is no issue.

Comment: @DineshSharma are you checking in simulator or on device ?